# How to use llvm target initialize function

Tags: build, clang, llvm, cross-compiling, klee

My Host System

: Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

: Host CPU: skylake

LLVM/Clang built with LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all option.

How to Use another target's Initialize Function in My code?

I modifying klee (symbolic execution tool) to run cross-platform Target's IR.

```
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"

int main () {
    ...
    // llvm::InitializeAllTargets(); -> Error    
    llvm::InitializeNativeTargets(); -> Success
    ...
}
```

In this case, error

```
${LLVM}/build/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:28: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeARMTargetInfo'
${LLVM}/build/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:29: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeBPFTargetInfo'
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **LLVMInitializexxxTargetInfo()** functions are used by **InitializeAllTargets()**, and the error message implys that you didn't link the required LLVM libraries.

**InitializeNativeTargets()** succeeded, because you maybe did't include your native arch in -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD.

You can add the following lines in your CMakeLists.txt to link LLVM Targets libraries:

```cmake
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS 
  ${LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD}
  )


# Build your .cpp with llvm macro to use LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
add_llvm_xxx_macro(YourOutputFile
  ...
  )
```